# Yii2 Executes the view twice

Tags: php, model-view-controller, layout, view, yii2

I've changed the index action for the login action and now the view executes twice like this [image]

Why this happend ?

Can anyone help me ?

This is the layout:

```
    <?php
/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\assets\LoginAsset;

LoginAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
        <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
        <?php $this->head() ?>
    </head>    
    <body class="fixed-header">
        <?php $this->beginBody() ?>

        <div class="login-wrapper">
            <?= $content ?>
        </div>

        <?php $this->endBody() ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

This is the view:

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\models\LoginForm */

use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'Tramite al dia - Login';
?>

<div class="bg-pic">
    <!-- START Background Pic 
    <img src="<?= Url::base() ?>/public/pages/assets/img/demo/new-york-city-buildings-sunrise-morning-hd-wallpaper.jpg" height="1200" width="1920" class="lazy">  -->    
    <!-- END Background Pic -->
    <!-- START Background Caption-->
    <div class="bg-caption pull-bottom sm-pull-bottom text-white p-l-20 m-b-20">
        <h2 class="semi-bold text-white">
            En la facilidad esta la felicidad de las personas.
        </h2>
        <p class="small">
            Te facilitamos el control del día a día con el tramite y gestión de sus documentos, <br> Tramite al día &copy; 2015
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- END Background Caption-->
</div>

<div class="login-container bg-white">
    <div class="p-l-50 m-l-20 p-r-50 m-r-20 p-t-50 m-t-30 sm-p-l-15 sm-p-r-15 sm-p-t-40">
        <!-- <img src="<?= Url::base() ?>/public/pages/assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="78" height="22"> -->    
        <p class="p-t-35">Accede a tu cuenta</p>
        <!-- START Login Form -->
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>        

        <!-- START Form Control-->
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>Usuario</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?= $form->field($model, "usuario")->label(FALSE); ?>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Form Control-->
        <!-- START Form Control-->
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?= $form->field($model, "clave")->passwordInput()->label(FALSE); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- START Form Control-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">                
                <?= $form->field($model, "recuerdaMe")->checkbox()->label(FALSE) ?>
                <label>Mantener sesión iniciada</label>                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right m-t-10">
                <a href="#" class="text-info small">Necesita ayuda?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Form Control-->
        <?= Html::submitButton("Entrar", ["class" => "btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10"]) ?>        

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        <!--END Login Form-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the controller

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;

class SiteController extends Controller {

    public $layout = "login";

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions() {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
        $model = new LoginForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()):
            return $this->redirect(["landing/index"]);
        else:
            return $this->render('index', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        endif;
    }    

    public function actionLogout() {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

}
```

First time this happend to me.

Comment: Context and code is what we need, clear proof of prior effort (in part so we can see what you tried already, so code with description is best) thats needed too. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: show controller also.

Comment: can you also add the name of the view files above and their path? I am not sure the file which you have mentioned as the view is the "login" or if your "layout" is named login.

Comment: the view name is index and the layout name is login

Comment: Strange. Could it be that you confuse any files? What makes me wonder is that the div with class bg-pic is not in the screenshot. If it would be the $content that is rendered twice then this should be also visible twice.

Comment: I've found the problem and it is the mod_rewrite mod from apache. is not working correctly so thats the result

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it's about the rendering in your layout files. Show the code of your `views/layouts/main.php` and if you have sub-templates those as well. E.g. if you have there multiple parts of the following code you will get the result you mentioned, e.g. multiple echo of `$content`.

```
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?= $content ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

Another possibility could be multiple call of `echo $this->render('yourview',...)` in your controller code. You should always return and not echo those render calls e.g. `return $this->render('yourview',...)` instead. Then is couldn't be rendered multiple times.

Comment: i also think is the layout but i can't see something different from the usual

Comment: I've found the problem and it is the mod_rewrite mod from apache. is not working correctly so thats the result.

Answer (score 1):

In case, you use `catchAll` mode, then it mb caused by the `debugger` toolbar whose content is served by the `catchAll` route.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/42

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5982